# Testing images imported in the component with Jest + React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

This is my package.json configuration:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    },        
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
    }
  },
```

And I have this image required inside the component:

```
const errorImage = require('../../../assets/images/load_error.png');
```

Which is trying to render this:

```
return (
            <Image
                source={ this.state.source }
                onError={ this._handleError } 
                resizeMode={resizeMode}
                style={[this.props.style, {height: this.state.height, width: this.state.width}]}
            />
        );
```

The `state.source`, after the handle error, is going to return the required errorImage. It works perfectly on the browser, no warnings or errors. But I have some troubles testing with jest.

But for some reason it cannot find the load_error.png image. This is my folder structure:

```
        ___mocks___
        --> fileMocks.js
        --> load_error.png
        __test__
        --> componentes
        --> --> imageComponent.test.js
        components
        --> imageComponent.js
```

No matter what I do, the error image gets empty.

This is my test:

```
const props = {
    author: 'Random Author',
    isSent: true,
    data:{origin:1},
    attachments:{
        4 : {
            type: 2, //file, pdf, word, etc...
            preview: 'pdf',
            url: 'file.png',
        },
    },
}

test('renders correctly', () => {
    const ActIndc = renderer.create(<Attachments {...props} />).toJSON();
    expect(ActIndc).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

When it don't found the `file.png` it should look for the error image, which is a require('error.png') inside the image component.

This is my folder structure:

[image]

The test is running in Attachements.test.js testing the attachment.js file, which uses the image component from the ui folder at the bottom of the image.

**Error message from jest:**

> Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something
> async in your test?
> Attempted to log "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`.
> in Image (at ....

Comment: your `png` imports are being mocked by `fileMock.js` - it basically skips loading any real files and just returns a stubbed string instead.  You could try mocking that file with `jest.mock(pathToImage)` and return your own mocked value (a string) then you may assert if the source has been updated with that mock string you provided.

Comment: @YuruiZhang where should I put the mock? in the jest file? Let me update the code of my test.

Comment: actually could you post your folder structure? if `assets` is outside of `src` I think jest might have some issues with it.

Comment: @YuruiZhang i had update a photo of the folder.

Comment: Thanks - could you post the part where your component looks for `file.png` and handles errors?

Comment: @YuruiZhang I don't handle that error, Jest does for me. In fact, the error didn't show in the chrome console. I had updated the warning error.

Comment: Right, in your question you mentioned `When it don't found the file.png it should look for the error image, which is a require('error.png')` - it'd be nice to see how that's handled... It could be that your test ended before some async action's callback is actually fired. It seems your code involves updating the state, in your test you should wrap the action that changes the state in `act` see https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#testrendereract

Comment: Yes, it update the state if the image doesnt exist, showing an error image. I will research about the act. Thanks. @YuruiZhang

Answer (score 8):

You can try to [manually mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks.html) the image in your test file using

```js
jest.mock('../../../assets/images/load_error.png')
```

Comment: the flaw I am facing here is in case of multiple <img> tags with different png's as src, there it just matches the first entry in mock sequence for all <img>'s, making test unreliable.

Comment: @ShailyGarg you can either mock each image or configure jest so that all `.pngs` are mocked. You can use a file matching a pattern as shown in Jest's [Handling Static Assets](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#handling-static-assets) section

Comment: I have tried doing that, the problem in my case is only `moduleNameMapper` is working and not `transform` configuration. Because of which all of my images are replaced by same mock string, where as i want to match image names with expected file name.

Answer (score 2):

If you're having problems with default or non-default exports for testing images in React or React Native, you can use this function:

```
jest.mock("../src/Icon", () => {
  return {
    default: "whatever.png",
  };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Providing a `rootDir` in the jest config object might solve this issue.

Something like:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "rootDir": "../",
    "preset": "react-native",
    // other config goes here...
  }
}
```

Refer: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#rootdir-string